# Using Ftpclientclass in c++

Tags: c++, ftp

I need to upload, delete and download files from ftp. I tried to look at  many libraries and found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8667/FTP-Client-Class) to be most suitable. I downloaded the source of the project and added those header files and cpp files in my project folder. I added that path to my Search Directory too. Then I wrote this simple program to test and upload file:

```
#include <ftpclient.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
nsFTP::CFTPClient ftpClient;
nsFTP::CLogonInfo logonInfo("localhost", 21, "anonymous", 
                                  "anonymous@user.com");


ftpClient.Login(logonInfo);


ftpClient.UploadFile(_T("D:\\file.txt"), _T("/upload/test.txt"));

ftpClient.Logout();
return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

> obj\Debug\main.o||In function `main':|
>   D:\Projects\FTP\main.cpp|4|undefined reference to`nsSocket::CreateDefaultBlockingSocketInstance()'|
>   D:\Projects\FTP\main.cpp|4|undefined reference to `nsFTP::CFTPClient::CFTPClient(std::auto_ptr<nsSocket::IBlockingSocket>, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, std::string const&)'|
>   D:\Projects\FTP\main.cpp|4|undefined reference to`nsFTP::CFTPClient::~CFTPClient()'|
>   D:\Projects\FTP\main.cpp|4|undefined reference to `nsFTP::CFTPClient::~CFTPClient()'|
>   D:\Projects\FTP\main.cpp|4|undefined reference to`nsFTP::CFTPClient::~CFTPClient()'|
>   D:\Projects\FTP\main.cpp|6|undefined reference to `nsFTP::CLogonInfo::CLogonInfo(std::string const&, unsigned short, std::string const&, std::string const&, std::string const&)'|
>   D:\Projects\FTP\main.cpp|9|undefined reference to`nsFTP::CFTPClient::Login(nsFTP::CLogonInfo const&)'|
>   D:\Projects\FTP\main.cpp|12|undefined reference to `nsFTP::CFTPClient::UploadFile(std::string const&, std::string const&, bool, nsFTP::CRepresentation const&, bool) const'|
>   D:\Projects\FTP\main.cpp|14|undefined reference to`nsFTP::CFTPClient::Logout()'|
>   D:\Projects\FTP\main.cpp|15|undefined reference to `nsFTP::CFTPClient::~CFTPClient()'|
>   D:\Projects\FTP\main.cpp|15|undefined reference to`nsFTP::CFTPClient::~CFTPClient()'|
>   ||=== Build finished: 11 errors, 0 warnings ===|

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to run the program correctly?

Comment: Maybe helps if you link with the correct library?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you link your application. You must link with the ftp client library.

Comment: Please tell me how to link with the library.

Comment: It depends on your compiler and OS. Check its documentation.

Comment: I can use CodeBlocks or VS 2012 on Windows 7. I couldn't find the documentation on the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8667/FTP-Client-Class) I found the source.